# Is there a compiled list of ERC20 with names and contracts?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, list

I see that Etherscan has a list of nearly 900 ERC20 token contracts, but with a number at the top that says"A total of 453,463 Token Contracts found". Is there a more compiled list out there of ERC20 tokens, the address and names of the token than what Etherscan is showing of the nearly 900?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check [tokenlists](https://tokenlists.org/), a community-led initiative to improve discoverability, reputation and trust in ERC20 token